# Install Nod32 antivirus silently?

Tags: installation, anti-virus, nod32, silent-install

I was hoping that I could find someone on here that may know if it is possible to install Nod32 on a client PC silently?

We have some software that will copy the MSI to the remote PC and run it with any specified parameters. The software needs you to import the license key file and tell it where the server is. Is there any way that these details can be pre specified so the user doesn't have to have any interaction on the remote computer.

Answer (score 1):

[Simplified remote installation](http://www.eset.com/business/remote-administrator): Closes security gaps while freeing IT staff from redundant, time-consuming work with improved search for unregistered clients. Also creates tasks to push install endpoints in parallel without further intervention.

Comment: comment from [IT Tech](http://superuser.com/users/40385/it-tech): Hi, thank you for your answer, but we do not want to remotely install this software, we specifically need to locally install it but find some sort of switch/answer file/config file to set it up for us.

Answer (score 1):

Run your msi with following parameters:

setup.msi /qn

As far as I remember near the .msi file there should be cfg.xml file with the special structure. See huge example [here](http://code.google.com/p/osbuild/source/browse/trunk/winxp/config/ESETSmartSecurity.xml?spec=svn31&r=31).

Comment: Thanks Vasiliy, I think that could help me out.
Just if anyone else stumbles across this post, this is what I have found:
Go to Tools (in the remote administrator) and click Manage packages and then create a package from the client installer which will contain the configuration.
And a link:http://kb.eset.com/esetkb/index?page=content&id=SOLN2227

Thanks for all your help again guys :o) TTFN